# How do I pass extra arguments to a `Fn` argument in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

To handle a command with a TG bot crate called Teloxide, I have to provide a `handle_command` function with a special signature:

```rust
pub async fn commands_repl<R, Cmd, H, Fut, HandlerE, N>(requester: R, bot_name: N, handler: H)
where
    Cmd: BotCommand + Send + 'static,
    H: Fn(UpdateWithCx<R, Message>, Cmd) -> Fut + Send + Sync + 'static,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<(), HandlerE>> + Send + 'static,
    Result<(), HandlerE>: OnError<HandlerE>,
    HandlerE: Debug + Send,
    N: Into<String> + Send + 'static,
    R: Requester + Send + Clone + 'static,
    <R as Requester>::GetUpdatesFaultTolerant: Send,
```

In the body of my `handler` function however, I want to access a Tokio Sender channel to send the data that was received from my telegram message.

So in code, this is what I would like to do:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(1);
    let bot = Bot::new(&cfg.telegram.api_key).auto_send();
    let bot_name: String = String::from("Tracker Bot");
    teloxide::commands_repl(bot, bot_name, handle_command).await;

    Ok(())
}

async fn handle_command(
    cx: UpdateWithCx<AutoSend<Bot>, Message>,
    command: telegram::Command,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    match command {
        telegram::Command::Help => cx.answer(telegram::Command::descriptions()).await?,
        telegram::Command::AddToken(token) => {
            let addr: H160 = token.parse()?;
            tx.send(addr).await?;
            cx.answer(format!("Token added: {}", token)).await?
        }
    };

    Ok(())
}
```

What is the best way to go about this? I thought about making the `Sender` a global variable, but this seems to create a lot of other problems. So is there any other way to get access to that variable inside the `handle_command` function?

Comment: I guess it comes down to the handler having a longer lifespan than anything declared in the main function, which would make this impossible. You could make the handler local, which would make the lifetime the same, but I don't think you would be able to access the local variables still. It's always possible to call another function from the handler, but this function would have hard time accessing the local variables as well. I'd look for a solution by packing the channel and handler in one module, which might help. But don't give up, there are people smarter than me, I might be wrong.

Comment: @IsawU yes I think I could make the handler a local closure, thereby gaining access to the Sender, but I am having trouble with getting async to work with the closure. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes that is problematic. I was on the other hand talking about a local function, which would allow you to use it as the handler, but lose the access to the local variables. I just keep on hitting walls whatever I think of.

Comment: I think the closure idea should work; can you provide details of the specific issue you're having with the closure?